# Should an empty search box return an error message or all results?

Tags: search, error-message, search-results, faceted-search

I'm currently working on 2 different websites: an events and a news websites. On both sites, a search interface with filter options is provided.

Initially, the search engine was build to return an error message if the user's query was empty. Since the search engine is looking for individual items in database and not specific content within the site, I'm thinking that returning all results (i.e. all news/events in my contexts) could be an interesting functionality. The user would then have the possibility to filter down his search.
This is how the search works on the [Financial Times](http://www.ft.com/).

What are your thoughts on this matter?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 9):

Moving to more human-like computer system, you could give to the system some human features:

- **Politeness** -- don't make use blame himself of his error (this effect is described by D.Norman in The Design of Everyday Things). Just point it gently.
- **Forgiveness** -- both computers and humans make errors. Forgive the user and he will forgive the system's error once.
- **Helpfulness** -- provide some helpful information instead of error message.
- **Memory** -- provide some information which is relevant to previous user search, i.e. based on his interest.
- **Moderation** -- don't provide all news, too much is not good. And old events and news are not best choice, too.
- **Fun** -- deliver some surprise and fun.

Comment: I don't see how your answer relate to the subject at all

Comment: I see where you're going with this but could you answer the question more directly. For instance, how does a "fun" answer help the user when he gets an empty search result?

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes it can help to take a look at what the giants are doing for tricky usability questions like this one.

- [Google](http://google.com), [Facebook](http://facebook.com), [YouTube](http://youtube.com), and [Twitter](http://twitter.com) do nothing and give no message.
- [Bing](http://bing.com) and [Baidu](http://baidu.com) take you back to the homepage and give no message.
- [Yahoo](http://yahoo.com) takes you back to the search homepage and gives no message.
- [Wikipedia](http://wikipedia.org) takes you to the search results page with no results shown and gives no message.
- [Amazon](http://amazon.com) takes you back to the homepage if the "All" category is selected. If another category is selected, either the homepage for that category or a listing of all results in the category will be shown. In either case, there is no error message.
- [LinkedIn](http://linkedin.com) lists all results.

**What can we conclude?** None of these sites give an error message. So, of the two options you provided, I would personally select showing all results.

You also have a third option, which is to **do nothing**. Giving zero feedback is very difficult to try to justify and *should generally be avoided in most cases*. Keep in mind that these sites are not in your domain, are all very popular and are mostly search-centric sites, so doing exactly what these sites do may not apply to yours.

However, an argument can be made for doing nothing:

- Showing all results might be confusing to users
- Lack of any change upon click could (maybe) be feedback in and of itself
- Leaving the page empty of any distractions may help the user focus on the search field and notice the mistake
- Precedent. We can safely assume almost all users have used one of the above websites before, and this is clearly common practice.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion there are no unsupported character in a search, even if I insert an emoji to the search field I will just get a no result and not an error.
(I don’t see any reason to add complexity to a widget)
Unless providing search results takes a long time and we can find unsupported character in an asynchronous way, 
if that is the case, use an error.

Answer (score 0):

Once I tested this with few users for a job search portal. It's a basic intention to get all results, people clear the search area and hit enter. Yes, it only happens in case, they have searched for something previously and that is written inside search box with filtered results below. I have seen instead of clicking back button, they clear the search area and hit enter to get back to all items.

Though it varies to users to users. First understand your target group and then implement this. Amazon does this but youtube not. So a proper case study with your potential users will give you actual feedback.